# Installing client side validation gem in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I am using rails 4. I have to do client side validation, so, I have installed gem

```
gem 'client_side_validations', git: 'git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git', branch: '4-0-beta'
```

But throws error while bundling .

```
Updating git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://rubygems.org/
Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from http://rubygems.org/
```

GemFile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'thin'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano', group: :development
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'better_errors'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1"
gem 'client_side_validations', git: 'git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git', branch: '4-0-beta'

#gem 'client_side_validations'
group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Please Help me?

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Answer (score 0):

In GEM file

```
gem 'rails4_client_side_validations', '~> 0.0.4'
```

In terminal run

```
bundle install
```